# Selenium fails to identify Frame element randomly [2 out of 5 times]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, frames, childwindow

```
                    w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        String parwind = w.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> windows = w.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println(windows.size());
        for(String handle : windows)
        {
            w.switchTo().window(handle);
            System.out.println(handle);
        }
        String mainwind = w.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println(mainwind);
        System.out.println(w.getTitle());
        w.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        w.switchTo().frame("menucontent");
        w.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='toggleTreeExpand']")).click();
        w.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        w.switchTo().frame(w.findElement(By.name("menuFr")));
        w.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='RegisterAttend']")).click();
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        w.switchTo().frame("content");
        w.switchTo().frame("commontoolbarFrame");
        w.findElement(By.name("create")).click();
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        w.switchTo().frame("content");
        w.switchTo().frame("f_query_add_mod");
        w.switchTo().frame("query_sub");
        w.findElement(By.name("first_name")).sendKeys("selenium");
        w.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='M']")).click();
        w.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='b_age']")).sendKeys("44");
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        w.switchTo().frame("content");
        w.switchTo().frame("f_query_add_mod");  
        w.switchTo().frame("main");
        w.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='findtl_tabspan']")).click();
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Set<String> windows1 = w.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println(windows1.size());
        for(String handles1 : windows1)
        {
            w.switchTo().window(handles1);
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        w.switchTo().frame("MainFrame1");
        w.findElement(By.name("blnggrpbut")).click();
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Set<String> windows2 = w.getWindowHandles();
        for(String handles2 : windows2)
        {
            w.switchTo().window(handles2);
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(windows2.size());
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        w.switchTo().frame("code_desc");
        w.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@name='resulted_row']")).click();
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        Set<String> windows3 = w.getWindowHandles();
        for(String handles3 : windows3)
        {
            w.switchTo().window(handles3);
            System.out.println(w.getTitle());
        }
        w.switchTo().frame("MainFrame1");
        w.findElement(By.name("close_button")).click();
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        w.switchTo().window(mainwind);
        w.switchTo().frame("content");
        w.switchTo().frame("commontoolbarFrame");
        w.findElement(By.name("apply")).click();
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Set<String> cancel = w.getWindowHandles();
        for(String can : cancel)
        {
            w.switchTo().window(can);
        }
        w.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Error : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //frame[@name='MainFrame1']

If I run this code for 5 times without changing any code, its executed 2 times successfully and other 3 times fails.

1st try - Pass
2nd try - fail
3rd try - fail
4rd try - pass
5th try - fail

Comment: @Mk08 can you give a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Selenium gets confused. I would recommend using

driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

The above will swap between newly opened windows. You can also use .First() to swap back and forth.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, If i execute the code out of 5 times only 3 times its success, the other two time it throws an error like "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //frame[@name='code_desc'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.45 seconds"

Comment: There is no method called driver.windowhandles.last

Comment: you seemed to have used "w" instead of driver. try w.windowhandles